# Value of using a better normal distribution

Tags: bayesian, information-theory, decision-theory

I tried to derive this on my own, but my stats education proved too far back…

(This is a problem in Bayesian decision theory – if that makes you uncomfortable, feel free to reformulate it)

Let's say I have options $o_i$ with payout $u_i \sim \mathcal N(\mu_i, \sigma_i)$. How much would I profit from reducing the variances to $\sigma_i ' = a_i \sigma_i$. For simplicity, let's assume the values of $a_i$ are given.

Example: I have 5 tasks that I can do. Either I do the one that I assume has the best return on investment straight away, or I investigate first which one is the best. Investigating has some cost attached and offers only a better estimate of the return on investment, not the exact value.

Comment: Unless your profit is related to the variability of the payouts when the prospect is repeated, there's no change because you have kept the *expectations* of the payouts the same.  Please, then, explain how the profit is computed.

Comment: In the scenario, you only get to pick a single option, and reducing the variability intuitively allows one to pick the best option with more confidence. The payout is not random in the frequentist sense, but means that we don't know $argmax u_i$. The gain should be related to the expected change in the max element. (Edit: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value_of_sample_information describes the discrete case)

Comment: I'm afraid that hasn't offered any useful information for understanding or answering the question.  There are open issues you need to address about how "best" is quantified and how "profit" is computed before anything useful can be said about this situation.  If you have a particular scenario in mind, it would be better to describe it rather than attempting to state an abstract question, because at present it looks like the abstraction has lost something essential about the problem.

Comment: Non-abstract: I have 5 tasks that I can do. Either I do the one that I assume has the best return on investment straight away, or I investigate first which one is the best. Investigating has some cost attached and offers only a better estimate of the return on investment, not the exact value. Hope that helps! I appreciate the help

Comment: It helps a great deal--but notice that it's not the question you asked, because until now you hadn't mentioned cost at all.  Please edit your question to reflect all the essential elements of your problem.  Don't try to use statistical terminology or notation unless you're truly comfortable with it: use language *you* understand (defining any unusual terms for us).

Comment: The cost wouldn't come into play -- either it's smaller, equal, or larger than the value of information. I managed to work most of it out... :-/

Answer (score 0):

*(I'm the original requester: I continued looking into this while waiting for an answer. Maybe this helps someone who finds this via search).*

### Expected Loss

The way to look at this: You get $U_i$ if you pick option $o_i$. If you had perfect information, you would get $\max_j U_j$. So by picking any option $o_i$, your loss is $\mathcal{L}(u) = U_i - \max_j U_j$.

As a simplification, we can assume the $\mu_i$ ordered, so that $\max \mu_i = \mu_1$. We can further transform the options so that $\mu_1 = \sigma_1 = 0$ by subtracting $U_1$ from the payouts (effectively increasing the standard deviation of the other options).

This leaves us with $\mathcal{L}(U) = - \max_j U_j$. The expected loss is now

\begin{align}
 \mathbb{E}\left(\mathcal{L}(\boldsymbol{U}) \right) &= \int \mathbb{P}(\boldsymbol{U}=\boldsymbol{u})\mathcal{L}(\boldsymbol{u}) d\boldsymbol{u} \\
&= - \int \mathbb{P}(\boldsymbol{U}=\boldsymbol{u}) \max_j(u_j) d\boldsymbol{u}
\end{align}

### Case $N=2$

For the case of $N>2$ things get a bit messy, so let's consider the case $N=2$ first, where we only get a second option $o_2$ with estimated payout $U_2$:

\begin{align}
 \mathbb{E}\left(\mathcal{L}(U_2) \right) &= \underbrace{\mathbb{E}(0 | U_2 \leq 0)}_{=0} + \mathbb{E}(U_2\, |\, U_2 > 0) \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \operatorname{erfc}{\left (\frac{\mu_2}{\sqrt{2}  \sigma_2} \right )}
\end{align}

The value of information is then the difference in expected loss (which is now easy to calculate):

\begin{align}
VoI(b) &= \mathbb{E}\left(\mathcal{L}(U')\right) - \mathbb{E}\left(\mathcal{L}(U)\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \operatorname{erfc}{\left (\frac{\mu_2}{\sqrt{2} b \sigma_2} \right )} - \frac{1}{2} \operatorname{erfc}{\left (\frac{\mu_2}{\sqrt{2} \sigma_2} \right )}
\end{align}

### Maximum of multiple random variables

The maximum of multiple random variables can be best understood in its cummulative distribution function:

\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(\max_j U_j \leq x) &= \prod \mathbb{P}(U_j \leq x)
\end{align}

(read as: the probability of the max being smaller than $x$ is the probability of all elements being smaller than $x$.)

The expected value is in terms of the density however, which means we need to take the derivative further down.

### Multiple options

I haven't been able to work this out properly. The loss is between the maximum individual loss and the sum of individual losses. This is a good enough approximation for me.